# What determines inebriated personality?

Tags: emotion, drugs

I've studied that alcohol impairs the functioning of the limbic system, slows functioning of the prefrontal cortex, which alters judgement and reason, and damages neurons leading to memory failure, death, etc.

Noting certain people seem to portray similar stereotypes drunk what determines what personality you have when intoxicated?

Is it a liberated version of more natural expression, free of stress?
A certain part of the limbic system damaged?